# Вывод значений в строку

Tags: mysql

Тривиальная структура: таблица товаров, свойства и их значения.

```
product
id  name
1   Товар 1
2   Товар 2
3   Товар 3

feature
id  name
1   Свойство 1
2   Свойство 2
3   Свойство 3

value
id  product_id  feature_id  value
1   1   1   Значение 1
2   2   1   Значение 2
3   3   1   Значение 3
4   1   2   Значение 4
5   2   2   Значение 5
6   3   2   Значение 6
7   1   3   Значение 7
8   2   3   Значение 8
9   3   3   Значение 9
```

Задача: вывести таблицу, где в первой колонке будут наименования товаров (без повторений), в остальных - значения свойств для каждого товара. В именах колонок значений свойств хотелось бы видеть id свойства (`feature.id`).

```
product.name    1           2           3
Товар 1         Значение 1  Значение 4  Значение 7
Товар 2         Значение 2  Значение 5  Значение 8
Товар 3         Значение 3  Значение 6  Значение 9
```

Comment: В SQL это принципиально невозможно. Разворачивать в горизонталь лучше на клиенте. В SQL можно только если заранее известен точный перечень колонок. В крайнем случае решаемо на стороне сервера в хранимой процедуре, за счет использования динамического построения запроса (но на клиенте выполнить эту работу на порядок проще)

Comment: @Mike, понимаю, что на клиенте проще. Вопрос только в производительности. Жаль, что нельзя.